# Can't "Resimultate" the foliage form the Procedural Foliage Tool from code

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm currently developing an editor widget for *unreal* that requires me to "Resimulate" the foliage generation using the [*procedural foliage tool*](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/BuildingWorlds/OpenWorldTools/ProceduralFoliage/QuickStart/).

[image: Figure 1]

Until now I was able to recreate the code from the "Resimulate" button (Figure 1) on click event, see the code bellow, but i am getting an error when I try to compile it even tho Intellisense doesn't give me any errors.

```
void ULandscapeHelper::Simulate()
{
    if (!AssignFoliageVolume())
    {
        if(GEngine)
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1,
                15.0f,
                FColor::Red,
                TEXT("Failed to get foliage volume"));
        return;
    }

    TArray<FDesiredFoliageInstance> FoliageInstances;
    if (FoliageComponent->GenerateProceduralContent(FoliageInstances))
    {
        if (FoliageInstances.Num() > 0)
        {
            FoliageComponent->RemoveProceduralContent(false);
            
            FFoliagePaintingGeometryFilter OverrideGeometryFilter;
            OverrideGeometryFilter.bAllowLandscape = FoliageComponent->bAllowLandscape;
            OverrideGeometryFilter.bAllowStaticMesh = FoliageComponent->bAllowStaticMesh;
            OverrideGeometryFilter.bAllowBSP = FoliageComponent->bAllowBSP;
            OverrideGeometryFilter.bAllowFoliage = FoliageComponent->bAllowFoliage;
            OverrideGeometryFilter.bAllowTranslucent = FoliageComponent->bAllowTranslucent;
            
            FEdModeFoliage::AddInstances(FoliageComponent->GetWorld(), FoliageInstances, OverrideGeometryFilter, true);
        }
    }
}
```

The error text:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl FEdModeFoliage::AddInstances(class UWorld *,class TArray const &)" (?AddInstances@FEdModeFoliage@@SAXPEAVUWorld@@AEBV?$TArray@UFDesiredFoliageInstance@@VFDefaultAllocator@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl USpawnTool::ResimulateAll(void)" (?ResimulateAll@USpawnTool@@QEAAXXZ)
```

I Found [this thread](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/437181/index.html) where the person asking add the exact problem that I was having but I wasn't able to implement the described solution. I still get the same error.